# count() error prioblem while posting JSON data to an API using PHP

Tags: php, api, data-transfer

I have got some data in PHP and trying to post to an API which has the data in JSON format. But when I post the data I keep getting an error of **count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable at LINE 428** ,, I am working on XAMPP version 7.2.1 and after checking online I changed the version to 5.6 but the error still persists.

**Sample data required by the API**

```
{"quote_id":112,
"country_residence":"Spain",
"physical_address":"*********",
"kra":"***********",
"policy_origin":"***********",
"policy_destination":"*********",
"with_spouse":1,
"spouse_id_passport":"B2345",
"spouse_name":"Spouse Name",
"spouse_dob":"1995-10-09",
"with_nok":1,
"nok_relation":"Son",
"nok_name":"NOK Full Names",
"nok_physical_address":"Physical address",
"nok_phone":"254**********",
"nok_email":"email2email.com",
"with_children":1,
"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"2015-05-23"}
  ]

}
```

**My PHP data together with CURL**

```
 array:18 [
      "quote_id" => 355
      "country_residence" => "297"
      "physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM"
      "kra" => "A123456789P"
      "policy_origin" => "297"
      "policy_destination" => "375"
      "with_spouse" => 1
      "spouse_id_passport" => "A1234567"
      "spouse_name" => "Martin"
      "spouse_dob" => "1977-02-09"
      "with_nok" => 1
      "nok_relation" => "Son"
      "nok_name" => "MNMNMN"
      "nok_physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM"
      "nok_phone" => "MNMNMN"
      "nok_email" => "NMMNMMNMNN"
      "with_children" => 1
      "children" => "{"child_name":"martin","child_dob":"2018-10-30"}"
    ]

//Call the curl function posting the data
$res = $this->global_Curl($data, 'api/travel/save-policy-meta');

//Curl function
    public function global_Curl($data, $url)
    {
        //dd($_ENV['API_ENDPOINT_NGINX_IP'] . '/' . $url);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ('http://digital.***********' . '/' . $url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //Prevents usage of a cached version of the URL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); 
        $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        // Log::debug($response);
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: Your `children` element does not match the API requirement. It looks like a string, not an array of objects.

Comment: @Nick Thanks,, how can I change it to match the API requirement,, am unable to figure out the bug

Comment: You need to edit your post with the code which is generating the API data.

Comment: @Nick I have tried with the code from the API,, seems there is a problem in children array that am passing thus throwing the error..

Comment: To post JSON you need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));`, don't think you need the option `CURLOPT_HEADER`, if your posting data you need `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Your "children" array in your main array doesn't seem like an array. Change it array format. Like,

```
array("child_name" => "martin", "child_dob" => "2018-10-30")
```

Also I don't see ',' separating the array elements.
EDIT

I don't know what you mean by `array:18`. But if you are using count() or json encoding the parameter must be an array. Like,

```
$array = array(
      "quote_id" => 355,
      "country_residence" => "297",
      "physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM",
      "kra" => "A123456789P",
      "policy_origin" => "297",
      "policy_destination" => "375",
      "with_spouse" => 1,
      "spouse_id_passport" => "A1234567",
      "spouse_name" => "Martin",
      "spouse_dob" => "1977-02-09",
      "with_nok" => 1,
      "nok_relation" => "Son",
      "nok_name" => "MNMNMN",
      "nok_physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM",
      "nok_phone" => "MNMNMN",
      "nok_email" => "NMMNMMNMNN",
      "with_children" => 1,
      "children" => $children,
    );
```

Comment: I have changed it but when I pass it as an array I get the following error **ErrorException
Array to string conversion**  seems aproblem converting to a string

Comment: I have converted the array to an object using `json_encode($children)` but it still throws the previous error

Comment: You have to out put the whole array. `json_encode($array);`. And you should set header as `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I have done exactly that but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

In the expected output...

```
"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"2015-05-23"}
  ]
```

It is assuming that you have an array of child objects, so it's an array of arrays.  As your only adding one child element, you need to wrap this into a second array (note the extra set of `[]` round the value)...

```
 $children = [['child_name' => $childname , 'child_dob' => $childdob]];
```

I think the idea is that if you had several child elements it could iterate through them...

```
 $children = [['child_name' => $childname , 'child_dob' => $childdob],
       ['child_name' => $childname2 , 'child_dob' => $childdob2],
       ['child_name' => $childname3 , 'child_dob' => $childdob3]];
```

Add this into your array using...

```
$array = array(
      "quote_id" => 355,
      "country_residence" => "297",
      "physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM",
      "kra" => "A123456789P",
      "policy_origin" => "297",
      "policy_destination" => "375",
      "with_spouse" => 1,
      "spouse_id_passport" => "A1234567",
      "spouse_name" => "Martin",
      "spouse_dob" => "1977-02-09",
      "with_nok" => 1,
      "nok_relation" => "Son",
      "nok_name" => "MNMNMN",
      "nok_physical_address" => "MMNMNMNM",
      "nok_phone" => "MNMNMN",
      "nok_email" => "NMMNMMNMNN",
      "with_children" => 1,
      "children" => $children,
    );
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I have done that but I get this error **1/1) ErrorException
Array to string conversion** I resolve by conrting to a string using `json_encode($children)` and I get the error I added in the question

Comment: You should NOT `json_encode()` `$children` , you only encode the overall array (`json_encode($array);')

Comment: When you said I should json_encode() the whole part did you mean `json_encode("children" => $children);` can`t seem to understand you.

Comment: I've updated the answer to try and be clearer.  If there is still a problem, can you check what the JSON is your getting and see what the difference is from what you need to send.

Comment: I have tested it,, am getting this JSON concerning children `"children":[{"child_name":"martin","child_dob":"2018-10-30"}]`   but on the API I require this `"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"2015-05-23"}
  ]` json format,,

Comment: When I post to the API I get this error **Array to string conversion**

Comment: Sorry - can't see the difference. (apart from 1 more space)

Comment: Am using curl to post the data,, could be an issue of sending headers

Comment: Things like this should be in the question!  Add the code which is posting the data to the question.

Comment: Have added the curl function in the question,, please check it